# Automatically load amp-iframe without scrolling

Tags: iframe, amp-html

There are several amp-iframes in a page ike this:

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="300" id="framebox" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups" layout="responsive" src="https://example.com/file.html">    
</amp-iframe>
```

I want to load one of the amp-iframes when the actual page is loading, not when the amp-iframe is in viewport.

Is there anything to do to make this happen?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found out a solution. Just load the iframe with a placeholder (using an image or HTML tag i.e. `<p>`).

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="300" id="framebox" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups" layout="responsive" src="https://example.com/file.html"> 

<amp-img layout="responsive" src="https://www.example.com/favicon.ico" placeholder="placeholder" width="450" height="450"></amp-img>

</amp-iframe>
```

I wanted to load an iframe which will load a script and grab the location of the parent window. But a user has to scroll down to the iframe to load the iframe.

So, I changed the height to 1 and placed it somewhere near the header.

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="1" id="framebox" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups" layout="responsive" src="https://example.com/file.html">



<amp-img layout="responsive" src="https://www.example.com/favicon.ico" placeholder="placeholder" width="450" height="450"></amp-img>

</amp-iframe>
```